# Looking for the 'neatest' way of reading exactly one record from database (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

The question described above can't be considered 'high priority', but it still bothers me.

Lets say I need to retrieve data from a database. And I know for sure, that the data is there, because if it wasn't the whole application would be broken. But I am not trying to read a 'set of results' just ONE result. So what is the 'neatest' way to achieve this?

My application is built on the **codeigniter** framework, and by utilising active records this is the best I came up with so far:

```
$result = $this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result();
$record = $result[0];
```

I know that I could design the query a bit different (and maybe shorter) e.g. by using get_where(...), but in the end it would still be a 'two-liner'.
This may be a 'luxury' problem, but I kinda hate the 'looks' of this code. Is there a way of making this a 'one-liner'?

On the other hand... if you think this is bad programming and I should not do this at all, tell me why and what I should do instead.

Your opinion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CI native way:

```
$record = $this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->row();
```

And you're good to go.

EDIT

Even a neater way:

```
$record = $this->db->get_where('some_table', "id = '$id'")->row();
```

`'$id'` doesn't have to be in quotes if the value is an integer, like here, though.

Comment: Thank you. THIS is what I have been looking for. The other answers do work as well. But this is clearly the way it is meant to be in codeigniter.

Comment: @Shomz I know.. when CI provides this through their active record class, why bother with `reset` etc. Manual is a good place to get started http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I know they work, but it clearly says Codeigniter in your question so I was surprised why nobody answered the right way. :)
@dakdad Exactly! :)

Comment: +1, I figured something like this existed, though after a quick look at the docs I couldn't find the `row()` method.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$result = $this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result();
$record = $result[0];
```

use

```
$record = reset($this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result());
```

Same thing can be used to get first FIELD of first ROW (Works as long as your codeigniter is returning records as arrays, i don't know cause i never used CI)

```
$firstfield = reset(reset($this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result()));
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't know about the 'reset' function. After reading phps documentation the 'current' function seems to be a viable alternative as well. Maybe an even better one, because I know the array has been untouched, and therefor reseting the pointer is not required?!

As for the CI ->result() this should always return an Array of Objects. In case the query doesnt match anything, it returns an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

Using `array_slice()`:

```
$record = array_slice($this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result(), 0, 1);
```

Using `array_shift()`:

```
$record = array_shift($result = $this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result());
```

Using `reset()`:

```
$record = reset($this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result());
```

In PHP 5.4:

```
$record = $this->db->from('some_table')->where('id',$id)->get()->result()[0];
```

---

My personal favorite is still `array_slice()` since it allows you to get any index you want, doesn't work with references and doesn't change the internal pointer position of the array. Still all of these solutions require you to work out what happens if `$result` is not an array (assuming you don't want warnings).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested all of these functions and - surprise - they all work! :) Anyway in my 'special' case array_slice() seems to be a bit of an overkill. I like array_shift(), reset() and (as mentioned in another comment) current() for this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the alternatives though, sometimes two lines is better than one...

Comment: could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: What I mean is, putting everything in one single, but more complex statement is not usually better that putting it in two clearer ones.  The 'correct' way as marked above is obviously fine, but some of the ways I've seen of slicing out records from an array make for complex and non-intuitive code.